# updating tableViewCell with modifications done in another view

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app am using tableview in which each cell am adding UIScrollView, in that scrollView again am adding  UIView(this view is adding from another view class). When touch actions  of view is performing but when i scroll the table all the modifications in view is reloading with what is there at the time of loading.

So how can we save the modifications of view which are done in another class in present tablecell.

in touchesEnded method am using

```
[music.createTableView beginUpdates];
[music.createTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[music.createTableView endUpdates];
```

Any help or suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure that you are not allocating your table and reloading , every time when viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, you are using NSArray to show data in rows of tableview. Inside that, you will keep another NSArray to show array of UIViews inside a every row. If you use NSDictionary to store data of UIView, you can set a flag in that dictionary which will change according to user touch. Hope it will help you.